# How to stop hovered text from moving?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When hovering over a menu item in my nav bar, the text on it and other items shift around: the hovered item widens, the other items narrow. I tried changing the margin and padding but it did not affect this issue.

```css
.profile-header-section {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 5rem;
}

.profile-nav {
    width: 80%;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.profile-logo {
    letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: larger;
}

.profile-links {
    display: flex;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 5rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.profile-links li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.profile-links li > a:hover {
    color: #d6c211;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #d6c211 0%, #ffc107 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
          <section class="profile-header-section">
            <header class="profile-header">
              <nav class="profile-nav">
                <div class="profile-logo">Profile</div>
                <ul class="profile-links">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </header>
          </section>
        </div>
```

How can the link text on the navigation bar be stopped from moving when the mouse cursor hovers over the links without losing the bold effect on hover?

Comment: The problem is due to the font-weight during the hover action. If you change the anchor's font-weight to be consistent during normal circumstances and hover, it should not be moving.

Comment: The hamburger part is a different question. If you search for how to create a hamburger menu you will find lots of help out there. If still stuck then put your code into a new question describing what isn't working well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to make a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.profile-header-section {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 5rem;
}

.profile-nav {
    width: 80%;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.profile-logo {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: larger;
}

.profile-links {
    display: flex;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 5rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.profile-links li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    
    /*transition makes it  smooth*/ 
    font-size:14px;
    transition:500ms;
    font-family:arial;
}

.profile-links li > a:hover {
    color: #d6c211;
    text-decoration: underline;
    /* the moving effect was caused due to the change in font weight*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <title>Profile Project</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <section class="profile-header-section">
            <header class="profile-header">
              <nav class="profile-nav">
                <div class="profile-logo">ProtFolio</div>
                <ul class="profile-links">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </header>
          </section>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

this should work for the moving effect and i can see you have just started learning .  creating a hamburger is easy but you should try to make it yourself you can also use google , that is the whole idea of programming "copy and paste" the code you think is needed ; just type "How to make a hamburger in html" in the google search bar and you will get a tons of results ;   "**Keep learning**"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yup before I asked questions, I always did google search first. But I would dig deeper into this topic of creating a hamburger menu. I did try replicate the code from other websites but the result was just kinda like a mess. I try will gain. Thanks.

BTW, can we use the font-weight for the hover effect? because I would like the text to be a bit bolder.

Comment: i have added another answer hope that one will be helpful :)

Comment: @MurtazaJoo: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.

Comment: … Additionally, further requirements added to a question should be addressed by editing the original answer, rather than posting a new one. You can delete one of your answers and incorporate any relevant information into the other.

Comment: @kenryuakuma: any requirements should be put in the question, not left as [comments](/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.profile-header-section {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 5rem;
}

.profile-nav {
    width: 90%;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.profile-logo {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: larger;
}

.profile-links { 
/*done some changes here*/

display: grid;
align-content: self-start;
  justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
     gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
   font: 120% system-ui;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.profile-links li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    
    /*transition makes it  smooth*/ 
    font-size:14px;
    transition:500ms;
    font-family:arial;
}

.profile-links li > a:hover {
    color: #d6c211;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight:900;
    /* the moving effect was caused due to the change in font weight*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <title>Profile Project</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <section class="profile-header-section">
            <header class="profile-header">
              <nav class="profile-nav">
                <div class="profile-logo">ProtFolio</div>
                <ul class="profile-links">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </header>
          </section>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```